# How to calculate animation duration by content height?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a custom BottomSheetController, whose height is dynamic and is set inside the controller using the preferredContentSize property. How do I calculate the duration of the animation depending on the height of the content so that the animation always looks smooth?

Demo - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVYbUdDLI9g

```
internal class PresentAnimation: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

func transitionDuration(
    using context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
) -> TimeInterval {
    context!.view(forKey: .to)!.frame.height * 0.002
}

func animateTransition(using context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let to = context.view(forKey: .to)!
    let finalFrame = context.finalFrame(
        for: context.viewController(forKey: .to)!
    )
    var frameWithOffset = finalFrame
    frameWithOffset.origin.y = context.containerView.frame.height
    to.frame = frameWithOffset
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: transitionDuration(using: context),
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0,
        options: .curveEaseInOut,
        animations: {
            to.frame = finalFrame
        },
        completion: { _ in
            context.completeTransition(true)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: If I understood u correctly, and u know certain content height before presentation - u could just create some multiplier to calculate duration. For example, multiply content height by 0.001. For 500 points height u'll get 0.5 seconds, for 300 points - 0.3 seconds etc. So u will have duration depending on height.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the answer, I tried to multiply the height of the content by a multiplier of 0.02 and it works. But the animation doesn't look smooth for different heights. It looks like there is another variable that we do not take into account

Comment: Updated code in the question

Comment: Try to remove those parameters "usingSpringWithDamping: 1" and "initialSpringVelocity: 0" from animation method. It works for me with more simple UIView.animate method.

Comment: Hey man, I have noticed u got an error in transitionDuration method! Correct system signature is "func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval". UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol requires certainly this method. Look on parameter name "context" in your implementation. Method from protocol has "transitionContext" parameter name. So maybe swift thinks u have not implemented this method. Fix and try

Comment: Not sure if removing the damping and velocity is good direction, system bottom sheet uses spring animation, it's just very delicate. You can observe it for example in the maps app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest clamping the animation time to some bounds like min 0.2 and max 0.5. Also adjust the spring damping and velocity for different heights. As the very small view shouldn't bounce with the same energy as bigger one (at least that way it will look more natural)

You can read more about them from this tutorial:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-animate-views-with-spring-damping-using-animatewithduration